# How can I write vector<unsigned char> to file, followed by an unsigned int

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2013

I have to group 5 `unsigned char` vectors (`data_length=5`). At the end of the group, I want to add an ID group and write them (group data+ its ID) to file. In which group ID types `integer`. I do that task as below code. Is it correct? 
 The bellow figure  shows what I am taking

[image]

```
#define random(x) (rand()%x)
std::ofstream filewrite("abc.raw", std::ios::out | std::ofstream::binary);
unsigned int iter = 0;
unsigned int data_length=5;
unsigned int ID_data=0;
//-------------Write data-------------//
while (iter<10){
    vector<unsigned char> vec_data;
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<data_length;i++){
        vec_data.push_back(random(256))
    }           
    std::copy(vec_data.begin(), vec_data.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(filewrite));
    //Write ID_data after vec_data
    filewrite.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&ID_data), sizeof(ID_data));
    ID_data++;
    iter++;
}
filewrite.close();
```

In additions, I want to extract the data to vector without the group ID. This is my code to extract data from the above file, but it does not remove the ID group. Could you help me to remove it?

```
//-------------Read data-------------//
std::ifstream file("abc.raw", std::ios::binary);
// Stop eating new lines in binary mode!!!
file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

// get its size:
std::streampos fileSize;

file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
fileSize = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

// reserve capacity
std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
     vec.insert(vec.begin(),
std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>(file),
std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>());
```

Comment: If this code is working, then I guess you should ask it in Code Review section.

Comment: Instead of giving an interpretation of what is going wrong, provide observations. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @MehrdadMomeny The first half of the question is unclear as to whether it works or not. The second part is definitely **not** working as intended, so [codereview.se] would be inappropriate at this time. Also, we are not a "section" :p

Comment: @Zak LOL, yep, section wasn't the correct term. :)

Comment: @all: Let see my update figure to make more clear question

Comment: BTW: VS has an integrated hex editor for files, use that to find out if what you get is what you expected. Further, you can use streams for text-based output, even to some extend for text-based serialization, but as soon as you want to create raw, packed bytewise representations of your memory content, they are not the right tool any more. Search the web for "serialization C++".

Comment: If your intention is to write binary data, use write/read instead of <</>>. Also, first you have to write the size of your vectors (which, I assume, might change).

Comment: Thanks. I updated it

Comment: Why is `random` a macro? Also, I'm still voting to close this as off topic, because the minimal but complete example is missing. Please delete your question, then study the posting guidelines and then ask a proper question.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Because it will be used many time. I think my question is very interesting for other people

Comment: Your question is relatively unclear, thus of limited use for others, the posting guidelines (did you even bother studying them?) give more detail what and why. Concerning your macro, there is no reason to use it, it could be a function instead. Further, but that's indeed irrelevant for your example, it produces a non-uniform distribution. For an example though, non-random numbers would be much better, i.e. if it just returned the sequence of values starting at zero, so that the behaviour is reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you use `while`, where `for` would be easier to read. BTW. you don't need two iteration variables. It is fine to iterate over `ID_data`.

```
for( unsigned int ID_data = 0; ID_data < 10; ++ID_data ) {
    // ...
}
```

second you don't need to produce a vector, that you never reuse, and then write the elements. It is fine do directly write the values.

```
for( unsigned int ID_data = 0; ID_data < 10; ++ID_data ) {
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < data_length; i++ )
        filewrite.put(random(256));

    filewrite.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&ID_data), sizeof(ID_data));
}
```

The second part: You can instantiate a vector with two iterators.

```
auto vec = std::vector<unsigned char>(std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>{file},
                                      std::istream_iterator<unsigned char>{});
```

But since you want to only read `data_length` values you might prefer:

```
auto vec = std::vector<unsigned char>{};

while( file ) {
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < data_length; i++ ) {
        char c;
        if( !file.get(c) )
            break;
        vec.push_back(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
    }

    unsigned int ID_data;
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&ID_data), sizeof(ID_data));
    // we don't use ID_data here, so it will simply be ignored.
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it has error as &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::get(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,_Elem)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'unsigned char' to 'char & and error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::read(_Elem *,std::streamsize)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'char *'   I think it must be file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&ID_data), sizeof(ID_data)); and char c;

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly. This should work now.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I correctly understood your question. Since I assume that you are having problems with binary writing, I am giving you a solution for just one vector. You can modify it easily:

```
void Write( std::ostream& os, const std::vector< std::uint8_t >& v, const std::int32_t id )
{
  std::size_t len = v.size();
  os.write( (const char*)&len, sizeof len );
  for ( auto e : v )
    os.write( (const char*)&e, sizeof e );
  os.write( (const char*)&id, sizeof id );
}

void Read( std::istream& is, std::vector< std::uint8_t >& v )
{
  std::size_t len;
  is.read( (char*)&len, sizeof len );
  v.resize( len );
  for ( auto &e : v )
    is.read( (char*)&e, sizeof e );
  std::int32_t id;
  is.read( (char*)&id, sizeof id );
}

int main()
{
  // write
  {
    std::ofstream os( "abc.raw", std::ios::binary );
    if ( ! os )
      return -1;
    std::vector< std::uint8_t > v;
    v.push_back( 0x10 );
    v.push_back( 0x20 );
    v.push_back( 0x30 );
    Write( os, v, 0x123 );
  }

  // read
  {
    std::ifstream is( "abc.raw", std::ios::binary );
    if ( ! is )
      return -1;
    std::vector< std::uint8_t > v;
    Read( is, v );
  }

  //
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about second question about extract raw data without ID